# ¿Como establecer el factor de clasificaciones del knn test sobre un conjunto de datos?

Tags: r

Desde el conocido conjuento de datos de iris, a partir de la longitud y anchura de sépalos y pétalos, quiero predecir las especies.

El conjunto de datos es este:

[image]

No sé cómo obtener clases del mismo tamaño para obtener los knn vecinos. He intentado:

```
data(iris)    
normalize <- function(x){
  return ((x-min(x))/max(x)-min(x))
}

iris_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(data[, c(1,2,3,4)],normalize))

iris_train <- c(iris_n[1:40, ], iris_n[51:90, ], iris_n[101:140, ])

iris_test <- c(iris_n[41:50, ], iris_n[91:100, ] ,iris_n[141:150, ])

iris_train_target <- c(iris_n[1:40, 5], iris_n[51:90, 5], iris_n[101:140, 5])
iris_test_target <-c(iris_n[41:50, 5], iris_n[91:100, 5], iris_n[141:150, 5])


require(class)
m1 <- knn(train = iris_train, test = iris_test, cl = iris_train_target, k=13)
table(iris_test_target, m1)
```

Sin embargo el compilador me dice :

```
Loading required package: class
Error in knn(train = iris_train, test = iris_test, cl = iris_train_target,  : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(cl) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes un problema en el subset.

```
iris_train_target <- c(iris_n[1:40, 5], iris_n[51:90, 5], iris_n[101:140, 5])
iris_test_target <- c(iris_n[41:50, 5], iris_n[91:100, 5], iris_n[141:150, 5])
```

Estás escogiendo la columna 5 del dataset `iris_n` cuando **únicamente** tiene 4 columnas según tu definición previa. Efectivamente, la orden:

```
dim(iris_n)
```

Devuelve:

> [1] 150   4

Así que tan solo tienes que definir las targets a partir del dataset original. Eso sí, se puede hacer un poco más compacto:

```
iris_train_target <- iris[c(1:40, 51:90, 101:140), 5]
iris_test_target <- iris[c(41:50, 91:100, 141:150), 5]
```

y el resto del código funciona sin problemas.